# Find reason for Brew-error when running brew list services

Tags: homebrew, laravel-valet

On my Mac, when I write brew services I get this result:

dnsmasq   error  512

httpd     error  256

mysql@5.7 started

nginx     error  256

php       error  19968

php@7.4   started

I was try write Valet install, Valet restart, brew services restart, but it's not helped.

Comment: Have you already fixed it? I got the same problem now

Comment: Same problem here, too, although my php@7.4 also shows an error.